# Mostrar ventana modal automáticamente solo la 1ª vez abra la página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, cookies

Estoy trabajando un Modal sencillo con la libreria http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com// de Jquery, quiero hacer que el Modal que tengo solo se abra una vez en el DOM y auque refresque la página (F5) el modal ya no se muestre de nuevo en pantalla.

La idea que me surge es manejarlo por Cookies pero no tengo el suficiente conocimiento.

Agradesco cualquier aporte.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#modal").iziModal({
        title: "Componentes de la Intranet",
        subtitle: "Tiempos S.A.S",
        transitionIn: 'fadeInDown',
        headerColor: '#006979',
        transitionOut: 'comingOut',
        width: 800,
        height: 1000
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/css/iziModal.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" data-izimodal-open="#modal">Modal</a>


    <div class="" id="modal" class="modal">
        <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/js/iziModal.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de enrollarte con una cookie más vale podrías almacenar un dato booleano en localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("modalAbierto", false);

$(elemento).on("evento al abrir el modal", function(){
   localStorage.setItem("modalAbierto", true);
})

function abrirModal()
{
   if(!localStorage.getItem("modalAbierto"))
   {
       abrirModal()
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar js-cookie, te facilitará el trabajo, mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var viewed = Cookies.get('viewed');

console.log(viewed)

if (viewed == true) {
  $(".modal").fadeOut();
} else if (viewed == undefined) {
  Cookies.set('viewed', true);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.modal h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal">
  <h1>Mi modal</h1>
</div>
```

Aquí hay un ejemplo funcional [EJEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/ug6k4jr1/) Ejecuta nuevamente después de ejecutarlo por primera vez.

Acá te dejo la documentación de [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), espero te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar Cookies.

Cookie: es una forma de salvar datos del lado del cliente con fecha para expirar.

La primera vez que el usuario abre la página iremos salvar una cookie con una duración X (usted lo decidirá) y siempre antes de exhibir el modal y salvar la cookie, vamos a verificar si esa cookie ya existe en el navegador del usuario, de existir es una señal de que el usuario ya visualizo la ventana emergente (PopUp o Ventanas Modales) y que no necesitamos exhibir nuevamente.

```
  <?php if($exibirModal === true) : // Si nuestra variable de control "$exibirModal" 
    es igual a TRUE activa nuestro modal y será visible a nuestro usuario. ?>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
     // id de nuestro modal
     $("#modalInicio").modal("show");
     });
   </script>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Con el control de Cookies listo, ahora vamos a nuestro JS responsable de llamar a la función que mostrará el modal, vamos a utilizar nuestra variable de control $exibirModal que hemos creado anteriormente, nuestro código quedará de la siguiente manera;

```
<?php
   #Iniciando la variable de control que permitirá mostrar o no el modal
   $exibirModal = false;
   #Verificando si existe o no la cookie
 if(!isset($_COOKIE["mostrarModal"])){
   # Caso no exista la cookie entra aqui
   # Creamos la cookie con la duración que queramos
 
    //$expirar = 3600; // muestra cada 1 hora
    //$expirar = 10800; // muestra cada 3 horas
    //$expirar = 21600; //muestra cada 6 horas
    $expirar = 43200; //muestra cada 12 horas
    //$expirar = 86400;  // muestra cada 24 horas
    setcookie('mostrarModal', 'SI', (time() + $expirar)); // mostrará cada 12 horas.
    # Ahora nuestra variable de control pasará a tener el valor TRUE (Verdadero)
    $exibirModal = true;
 }
?>
```